# Youtube green screen in Chrome while running Ubuntu in VMplayer

Tags: google-chrome, 14.10, vmware

I've got Ubuntu 14.10 running in VMplayer.  While Youtube works ok in Firefox, it will only show a green screen in Google Chrome but still play the sound correctly.  The Chrome version is `40.0.2214.85 beta`.

I tried to enable the `Override software rendering list` option, as suggested in [this Webupd8 post](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/enable-hardware-acceleration-in-chrome.html), but it didn't change anything.

Any idea ?

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you fixed it ?

Comment: Nope, still there...